How to solve this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory?
Masuds-MacBook-Air:core masudrana$ php artisan migrate
In Connection.php line 760:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from vehicle_types where status = 1 order by name asc)
Why is this issue showing? Can you help me to solve this issue?

In your .env file change localhost to 127.0.0.1

how did you identified its his host misconfiguration without proper context

Mkae sure that your db connection info are updated in .env file.
DB_CONNECTION = mysql
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
DB_PORT = 3306

